# Can Postman send gRPC request with specific authority

Tags: postman, grpc, authority

I'm trying to send gRPC requests with Postman to my backend, which used an Envoy as the gateway. I have a domain name, which points to the gateway.

When I send a gRPC request with Postman, it works as expected.

[image]

As you see, I get the response.

However, if I tried to send a gRPC request with pure IP, I always got an gRPC error `12`.

[image]

As you see, I used the pure IP, which is exactly the IP address of my domain name, and I set the `authority` in the metadata of request. However, it didn't work.

I checked the log of Envoy and I found that the gRPC request had the wrong `authority` value. Its value was `111.111.111.111:2222`, which should have been `www.example.com:2222`. Envoy can't find a route rule for this `authority`, this is why I got the error.

I'm confused now. I set `authority` in metadata but it doesn't seem to work as expected...

I've google a lot about grpc and Postman, but I didn't find anyting useful about this issue.